# Resizing icon using imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimageview

I've got the following code (updated):

```
    // Set cell row height
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension  // Auto-size cell based on content

}

// Set cell content
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    let weatherObject = forecastData[indexPath.section]

    // Convert UNIX time into readable format
    let sunriseUNIX = weatherObject.sunriseTime
    let sunriseDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(sunriseUNIX))

    let sunsetUNIX = weatherObject.sunsetTime
    let sunsetDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(sunsetUNIX))

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let sunriseConv = dateFormatter.string(from: sunriseDate)
    let sunsetConv = dateFormatter.string(from: sunsetDate)


    cell.textLabel?.text = weatherObject.summary
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Max: \(Int(round(weatherObject.temperatureMax))) °F / Min: \(Int(round(weatherObject.temperatureMin))) °F \nWill feel like \(Int(round(weatherObject.apparentTemperatureMax))) °F \nSunrise: \(sunriseConv)   Sunset: \(sunsetConv) \nRelative Humidity: \(Int((weatherObject.humidity)*100))% \nMoon Phase: \(round(weatherObject.moonPhase))"
    cell.detailTextLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: weatherObject.icon)
    cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true  // clipping will help check actual frame of image
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.setNeedsDisplay()  // try to reset display, if not updating your image scale automatically

    return cell
}
```

...(Still) yielding the following result:

[image: result of code]

I'm trying to get the 'icon' images sized 10 x 10 pixels, yet the above code doesn't work. Regardless of the values in `CGRect`, the 'icons' remain the same size.

Any pointers, alternatives would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add height and width constraints equal to 50

Comment: UIImageView having contentMode property with the help of that you can set the image content as you want

Answer (score 0):

You should set up the content mode of the images properly in order to scale them to the correct size.

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as shown under:

```
var newImgThumb : UIImageView
newImgThumb = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 70))
newImgThumb.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Hope u got it!!!

Comment: Bhai, question Swift 3 ma 6, ane taro answer Swift 2 ma.. Ene Swift 3 ma convert kar.

Answer (score 0):

Set content mode of cell image view as `scaleAspectFit`

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: weatherObject.icon)
cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true  // clipping will help check actual frame of image
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
//cell.setNeedsDisplay()  // try to reset display, if not updating your image scale automatically
```

A good advice for you, **Use Custom tableview cell** and set all elements according to your choice/requirement.

[Here is reference tutorial for Custom Tableview cell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/). Let me know, if you face any problem with Custom Tableview Cell.

Custom tableview cell, gives flexibility to arrange all cell elements according to your need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Krunal.  Unfortunately, the icons are still not resizing.  I've updated my code above.  Maybe someone can point me in another direction?

Comment: @J. Dorais, a good advice for you, Use Custom tableview cell and set all elements according to your choice/requirement. Let me know, if you face any problem with Custom Tableview Cell.